# How should I cite an open letter with a large number of signatories?

Tags: citations, citation-style

When citing an open letter, is it appropriate to cite all of the signatories as authors?

I would like to cite the following open letter: [Dear Oprah Winfrey: 142 Writers Ask You to Reconsider *American Dirt*](https://lithub.com/dear-oprah-winfrey-82-writers-ask-you-to-reconsider-american-dirt/)

The letter has 142 signatories.  The byline says it is by "141 Writers" with no particular author name.  So would I cite the author as "141 Writers" or would I cite it as though the signatories are the authors?

This particular paper is in APA but I would be interested in information about MLA as well in case it comes up, since I use MLA in the classes that I teach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an answer from APA Style on twitter.  They say to use the group name that appears in the byline, and make sure to capitalize "Writers".

Source: https://twitter.com/Zupancia/status/1309502673406881792